# CSS: Why is Flex gap ignored?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple flex box containing three divs. I want to set a minimum gap between those divs yet, despite having set the `gap` property, each div still butts up against another. Can anyone tell me why `gap` is ignored?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Cards</title>
  <style>
    .card {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-radius: 2px;

      margin-top: 2rem;

      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      gap: 4rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div>LS</div>
    <div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum ducimus consectetur reiciendis, autem tempore recusandae repellat modi a perferendis voluptates similique ex, aut accusantium sint, facilis, atque natus dolores error optio praesentium. Ad, expedita, nihil.</div>
      <div>RS</div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div>LEFTHAND SIDE</div>
    <div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum ducimus consectetur reiciendis, autem tempore recusandae repellat modi a perferendis voluptates similique ex, aut accusantium sint, facilis, atque natus dolores error optio praesentium. Ad, expedita, nihil.</div>
    <div>RIGHTHAND SIDE</di>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

I'm using Safari 14.0.3

Comment: What are you talking about, what is butting together here ...? Adding `.card div { outline: 1px solid red; }` clearly shows that the child divs of your `.card` elements do _not_ "butt up against another" ...

Comment: Looks like it's a Safari issue. I'm using 14.0.3 but `gap` support was only introduced with 14.1

Comment: Add add those details to the question, answer it yourself, and resolve it so future people can find it.

Answer (score 2):

Safari only began supporting flexbox's `gap` property with [version 14.1](https://caniuse.com/flexbox-gap).

The styling in the question is correct but Safari 14.0.3 does not support flexbox's `gap` property.